# What could cause poor drainage in the kitchen and baths?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, septic

After having my septic system (tank) cleaned about a month ago, I've noticed a foul odor in the bathroom of the master bedroom. I've also noticed the smell outside near the master bedroom.  It's not smelling in any other part of the house. A couple of weeks later I noticed that the kitchen sink is not draining properly, but only on the right side. The bathtub isn't draining properly nor are the toilets flushing properly. The toilets flush as if they're not getting enough pressure or water flow. After flushing the toilet twice and sometimes a third time then it will flush where you can hear the flushing sound that lets you know it has flushed.

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check to see if the sewer line vent pipe(s) that go up through your roof are plugged up. A plugged vent line cap prevent proper sewage water flow in the drain lines.

The foul smell in and around the bedroom area could also be caused by a plugged vent pipe that is keeping sewer gasses from dispersing in the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

The vent being blocked is one possibility but equally possible is that your sewer line is blocked and backing up.  Have you checked all of your drains to see if anything is backing up? It will usually back up at the lowest drain in the house unless the blockage is higher up.  Check all floor drains, laundry drains, toilets, sinks, etc.

Sewer gas is toxic so calling a plumber is advisable if you can't figure it out.